# Reducir tamaño de un Dataframe y rellenar huecos resultantes con los datos disponibles en otras filas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un dataframe gigante creado con Python mediante Pandas, del cual querría reducir su volumen eliminando filas innecesarias y rellenando otras filas que están incompletas. Por ejemplo, tengo este dataframe:

```
         DIAMETRO   POSICION   DIST
TIEMPO                             
0.1           3.3               NaN
0.2           3.6               NaN
0.3                        1   0.26
0.4           3.8               NaN
0.5           3.2               NaN
0.6                        2   0.13
0.7           3.7               NaN
0.8           3.5               NaN
0.9                        3   0.99
1.0           3.1               NaN
1.1           3.0               NaN
1.2                        4   0.84
```

Como veis, en el TIEMPO 0.3 tengo la POSICION (=1) y la DISTANCIA (=0.26) y me gustaria rellenar la casilla DIAMETRO que esta vacía con la información de la fila de abajo (la que solo contiene la información sobre DIAMETRO. Y luego borrar esas filas que solo contienen datos de diametro unicamente. Haciendo esto, el resultado debería ser este:

```
         DIAMETRO   POSICION   DIST
TIEMPO                             
0.3            3.8          1  0.26
0.6            3.7          2  0.13
0.9            3.1          3  0.99
```

Como veis, se han eliminado las filas 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, etc., que solo contenían diámetros, y se han rellenado las casillas de diámetro vacía de las filas que quedan.

El problema es no conozco ninguna función de la librería Pandas capaz de hacer esto. He buscado por internet pero no veo ejemplos de casos similares. ¿Alguien sabría alguna forma de hacerlo?

He intentado mediante un bucle:

```
for i in range (1, len(df['TIEMPO'])):
    fila_abajo= df['DIAMETRO'][i+1]

#Pongo i + 1 para que me seleccione la casilla de la fila siguiente a la vacía.

    valores = {'DIAMETRO': fila_abajo}

#Y ahora relleno las casillas vacias con el valor de la fila de abajo que si tiene datos 

df.fillna(value=valores)
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado hacer? Recuerda que las preguntas que no muestran ningún esfuerzo no se apegan a los lineamientos del sitio. Por favor agrega lo que has intentado hacer o haz investigado.

Comment: Es verdad. Lo que he intentado hacer antes ha sido un bucle:

`for i in range (1, len(df['TIEMPO'])):`
 `fila_abajo= df['DIAMETRO'][i+1]`

Pongo i + 1 para que me seleccione la casilla de la fila siguiente a la vacía.

`valores = {'DIAMETRO': fila_abajo}`

Y ahora relleno las casillas vacias con el valor de la fila de abajo que si tiene datos 

`df.fillna(value=valores)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Utilizando el siguiente `dataframe` como ejemplo:

**Nota:** Cuando crees una pregunta siempre agrega un ejemplo reproducible. Crear un ejemplo para resolver la duda lleva tiempo y es mejor enfocarlo en la solución y no en intentar emular tus datos.

```
       D    P     d
T                  
0.1  3.3  NaN   NaN
0.2  3.6  NaN   NaN
0.3  NaN  1.0  0.26
0.4  3.8  NaN   NaN
0.5  3.2  NaN   NaN
0.6  NaN  2.0  0.13
0.7  3.7  NaN   NaN
0.8  3.5  NaN   NaN
0.9  NaN  3.0  0.99
1.0  3.1  NaN   NaN
1.1  3.0  NaN   NaN
1.2  NaN  4.0  0.84
```

Utilizamos [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) para rellenar hacia atrás, es decir, cuando hay una fila vacía se utiliza el valor de la fila siguiente para rellenarlo

Y luego utilizamos [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) para eliminar las filas que tienen `NaN`.

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'T': np.arange(0.1,1.3,0.1),
                   'D': [3.3,3.6,np.nan,3.8,3.2,np.nan,3.7,3.5,np.nan,3.1,3.0,np.nan],
                   'P': [np.nan,np.nan,1,np.nan,np.nan,2,np.nan,np.nan,3,np.nan,np.nan,4],
                   'd': [np.nan,np.nan,0.26,np.nan,np.nan,0.13,np.nan,np.nan,0.99,np.nan,np.nan,0.84]})

df.set_index('T', inplace = True)
# Rellenamos hacia atrás
df['D'].bfill(inplace = True)

# Eliminamos los NaN
df.dropna(inplace = True)
print(df)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
       D    P     d
T                  
0.3  3.8  1.0  0.26
0.6  3.7  2.0  0.13
0.9  3.1  3.0  0.99
```